# General solutions of trig equation $4\sin(x) - 3\sin(2x)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The question is :

$4\sin(x) - 3\sin(2x)=0$, find in terms of degrees the general solution to that equation.

I got $\sin(x)=0$ and $2 - 3\cos x=0$

From this I then get $180n, 48.19 + 360n, 311.81 + 360n \text { (to 2 decimal places)}$

However, the answers are $180k, 48.19 + 360n , -48.19 + 360n \text { (to 2 decimal places)}$,

I was wondering why am I incorrect? 
I was also wondering why is one of the constants different to the rest ($k$ and then $n$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two answers are identical: $311.81=360 - (48.19)$.

Comment: So if I were to have either as an answer, it would be correct? Also, I was wondering why the constant infront of 180 is k but then the other answers are n. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, you can write the answer either way. $k$ and $n$ are integer variables and it doesn't matter what symbols you use.

Comment: Sorry, I have another question. So as 311.81 is the same as 360 - 41.19 why is it when i put n=2 into 360(n) - 48.19 do I not get the same answer as 311.81 + 360(n) ?

Comment: The two answers do not match for a **fixed** $n$, but the set of solutions is the same.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  

Some authors use positive angles throughout as they see the solutions as traversing the unit circle counterclockwise; others will use both positive and negative angles (e.g. when describing AC circuits, angles represent whether the current is leading (positive) or lagging (negative).)